# Accessing the data from the gridview to download a PDF document in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, pdf

```
     FID            NAME    
     M001           Faculty1    download
     M002           Faculty2    download
     M003           Faculty3    download
```

The above shown is my grid view containing details of faculty and the download link indicates the pdf form of the faculty to be downloaded.

```
       va = (string)Session["FID"];




       protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataRow dr = GetData("select * from Personal_det where FID ='"+va+"'").Rows[0];
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
    Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, m);
        Phrase phrase = null;
        PdfPCell cell = null;
        PdfPTable table = null;
        BaseColor color = null;
        Paragraph para = null;
        Font times = null;
        BaseFont bfTimes = null;



        doc.Open();
        table = new PdfPTable(2);

        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase("Faculty Profile", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //table.SpacingBefore = 20f;

        cell.Colspan = 2;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 30f;


        //FID
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Faculty Code:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("mahe" + dr["FID"].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Name
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Name:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase(dr["Name"].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);


        //Date of Birth
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Date of Birth:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DOB"]).ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy"), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Phone Number
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Phone Number:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase(Convert.ToInt64(dr["MobileNo"]).ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Mail Id
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Email ID:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase(dr["EmailId"].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Address
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Res Address:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["add1"] + "\n " + dr["add2"] + "\n " + dr["add3"] + "\n " + dr["Pincode"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        table.SpacingAfter = 30f;
        doc.Add(table);
 }
```

My grid view code is shown below

```
           <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
         Width="294px" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"  

         >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FID" HeaderText="FID" SortExpression="FID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
           <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" 

      CommandArgument="&lt;(&quot;Value&quot;)&gt;" OnClick="DownloadFile"

                        Text="Download" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>




        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [FID], [Name] FROM [Personal_det]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The problem arises is whenver i click the download button the PDF of 1st faculty is been displaying even if i click download button for other faculty also,I need to get data for every faculty How to do get the pdf?

My requirement is that the paricular pdf should be downloaded for the particular FID and it shouldnot download only for the first FID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside you itemtemplate

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" 
  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FID")%>' CommandName="DownloadFile" OnClick="DownloadFile" Text="Download" />
```

In .cs

```
 protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  string FID = Convert.ToString(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument); 
 DataRow dr = GetData("select * from Personal_det where FID = '"+ FID +"'").Rows[0];
  .....
  //other codes
  }
```

May this line of code will help solving your problem

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting the FID into the session. As soon as User clicks on Download button, at the same time the function getting called. Its starting from very first row and will take first ID. Now it will be assigned in the session variable and same process is repeating for each click. You have to manage the event through RowDataBound of the GridView.

Comment: You can refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx).